# Determine which kernel ships with which Ubuntu version

Tags: 14.04, kernel, versions

Is there a way to figure out, without having to actually install Ubuntu, which "stock" version of the kernel (ie: which I'd see when executing `uname -a`) ships with each release of Ubunutu, assuming I don't enable the "install updates from online" feature during the installation?

I'm trying to figure out the default kernel that ships with:

- 14.04.1
- 14.04.2
- 14.04.3
- 14.04.4

I'd like to be able to confirm that there is a jump from the 3.16.X line to the 3.19.X line between 14.04.3 and 14.04.4, or if there's something I'm overlooking.

[In previous releases, the file list contains the pre-built signed kernel image.](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.5-alternate-amd64.list) However, in new releases, [I just see the kernel source package, and not a pre-built signed image which provides the version number](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.list), so I would need to somehow map the source package with the associated release number.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

14.04 and 14.04.1 had kernel 3.13

14.04.2 - 3.16

14.04.3 - 3.19

14.04.4 - 4.2

See [LTS HWE Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

The idea is that new installs on new hardware may need a new major kernels. Older kernels also get security and some hardware enablement updates.

But if you initially installed e.g. 14.04.2, and did updates, the Ubuntu version number will change to 14.04.3, then 14.04.4, but you will still have kernel 3.16.

If you want to install kernel 4.2 to the system that was not initially installed from an Ubuntu 14.04.4 image, you can run

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

Comment: If 14.04.4 uses 4.2, then something must be wrong with my installation. I had a 14.04.3 LiveUSB installer, and enabled the "install updates from online" option, and I now have Ubuntu 14.04.4 (confirmed via `lsb_release -a`), and kernel 3.19.0-51 (confirmed via `uname -a`). Does the "install updates from online" option not provide an updated kernel during installation?

Comment: All is correct. Updates do not change major kernel versions.

Comment: I'll mark this as accepted when I can in a few minutes. In the meantime, where did you gather this info? Is there a release notes page or something I can reference in the future?

Comment: I added a link.

Comment: One last question: is there a command to query the latest kernel version for each ubuntu version (ie: I think its 3.16.0-60 for 14.04.2, 3.19.0-51 for 14.04.3, etc), or some other way to know the latest kernel release for each point release? Thanks!

Comment: Something like `dpkg -l | grep linux-image-generic`

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using the `rmadison` tool that ships with `devutils`, but this also helps. :)